# Passing id using jquery to URL

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, url

My story board :

I have a table that viewing data from mysql using php.
Every rows have a button to preview the one row into a modal bootstrap.

Now, Can I get one field (cell perhaps) of data to passing to url ?
In my case which is no_request would be a parameter.
Because this one field will be a parameter

This is my view :

```
<table>
<tbody>
<?php
   $no = 1;
   foreach($data_request as $data) {
?>

<tr>
    <td class="center"><?php echo $no++.". ";?> </td>
    <td class="sorting1" id='no_request'><?php echo $data['code_office'].'/'.$data['code_departement'].'/'.date ('m', strtotime($data['month'])).'/'.$data['id_request'];?> </td>
    <td class="center"><?php echo "$name"; ?></td>
    <td class="center"><?php echo date ("d-m-Y, H:i ",strtotime($data['waktu_mulai']));?></td>
    <td class="center"><?php echo $data['complaint'];?></td>                                            
    <td class="center"><span class="label label-warning"><?php echo $data['status_request'];?></span></td> 
    <td class="center"><?php echo date ("d-m-Y, H:i ",strtotime($data['closing_request']));?></td>                                            
    <td  class="center">
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
            <i class="halflings-icon white trash"></i> Close
        </a>

        <a class="btn btn-success" href="#" id="print" req_id="<?php echo $data['id_request']; ?>">
            <i class="halflings-icon pencil"></i> Print  
        </a>         
    </td>
</tr>                                    

<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table> 

    <div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h1>Print Preview</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
           <p id="id_preview"> </p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

            // This is the problem
            <a href="<?php echo base_url().'control_closing/generate_pdf/no_request ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Create PDF</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>   
        </div>

    </div>


    <script>
       $('.btn-success').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var $this = $(this);

            var $trData = $this.closest('tr').clone();
            $trData.find('td:last').remove();

            var $thData = $this.closest('table').find('thead').clone();
            $thData.find('th:last').remove();

            var $table = $('<table border="2"></table>');
            $table.append($thData).append($trData);

            $("#id_preview").html($table);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });

       function passing_id_to_url{
            //How to passing no_request to url ?
       }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Jquery, and I assume you want to POST the data back to the URL, you could use a hidden form:

```
<form id="pdf<?php echo $no++;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="office" value="<?php echo $data['code_office'];?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="complaint" value="<?php echo $data['complaint'];?>" />
    ....
    <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="submit(<?php echo $no;?>)>Create PDF</a>
</form>
```

And then use Ajax to post the form data

```
function submit(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'/control_closing/generate_pdf/no_request',
        type:'post'
        data:$('form#pdf'+id).serialize(),
        success:function(html) {
            modal(html);
        }
    });
}

function modal() {
   //.... Code for modal
}
```

Comment: Thanks dave. By the way, I am still confused.
Try this http://jsfiddle.net/UW38e/, 

From that url, you will see, how to make the text on 'alert' will be sending to url as parameter.

Thanks Before